# Preserving dots of an acronym while indexing in Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

If i want Lucene to preserve dots of acronyms(example: U.K,U.S.A. etc), which analyzer do i need to use and how? 
I also want to input a set of stop words to Lucene while doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [WhiteSpaceAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html) will preserve the dots. A [StopFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.html) removes a list of stop words. You should define exactly the analysis you need, and then combine analyzers and token filters to achieve it, or [write your own analyzer](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#head-41181bec0333f30142a09aa6f50fdc32895a3698).

Answer (score 0):

[StandardTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html) preserves the dots occurring between letters. You can use StandardAnalyzer which uses StandardTokenizer. Or you could create your own analyzer with StandardTokenizer.

Correction: StandardAnalyzer will not help as it uses StandardFilter, which removes the dots from the acronym. You can construct your own analyzer with StandardTokenizer and additional filters (such as lower case filter) minus the StandardFilter.

Comment: thanks for ur comments...FYI, i'm already using StandardAnalyzer  in my code:
protected readonly StandardAnalyzer _analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(stop_words);
but it removes dots from acronyms...